# How to get TimeToLive working on JmsTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms, spring-messaging

I am trying to set the TTL on JmsTemplate but the messages never expire. When I set a TTL on a message using the ActiveMQ Web Console it does expire after the set period.

This is what I have now:

```
<bean id="shortTtlJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="explicitQosEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="deliveryPersistent" value="false"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="10000"/>
    <property name="timeToLive" value="10000"/>
</bean>

<bean id="shortTtlJmsMessagingTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="shortTtlJmsTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

The documentation only says that I have to set *explicitQosEnabled* to *true* but apparently this is not enough. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/jms/124544-unable-to-set-jmsexpiration-on-outbound-messages

Comment: Ah! Clock sync issue ;) It's solved now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it wasn't working due to a clock synchronisation issue. The clocks are in sync now and everything is working as expected.